# How to select rows based on other tables - MySql

Tags: mysql, join, if-not-exists

I have tables like this:

CheckTable

```
(id) (user_id)
[0]  [403]
```

UserTable

```
(id)  (username)
[403] [hello]
```

I want to select only the rows from the `UserTable` that do not have the user id row in the `CheckTable`

I could just select all the users, loop through the rows and then run another query checking if the `user_id` is in the `UserTable`, but that would be slow.

Is there any MySQL query that could join and select.

Comment: There certainly is a join query, outer join to be more specific. There is also a `NOT EXISTS` condition. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT Whatever FROM UserTable
WHERE UserTable.username NOT IN 
(
  SELECT CheckTable.user_id FROM CheckTable
);
```

If this is not suitable, please expand. Possibly with table definitions - (SHOW CREATE TABLE My_Table\G) and some sample data - (INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES(....)), and finally, the result you want with the logic you used to obtain it.

With further research, you might also find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699424/what-the-difference-between-not-in-and-not-exists-in-oracle-query) interesting - and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null). As a generic response, substituting `NOT EXISTS` for `NOT IN` might be the way to go - YMMV.

Comment: Should probably be `CheckTable.user_id` instead of `CheckTable.id`. On a different note, I've heard it mentioned more than once that in MySQL the `LEFT JOIN` + `WHERE IS NULL` method for some reason works better than either NOT IN or NOT EXISTS. Somewhat odd, I know. But in any event, if I was suggesting NOT IN, I would also make sure to mention it's behaviour with lists containing NULLs.

Comment: Your point about `NOT NULL`s is well made, but I did include two links to discussions about the `NULL` situation. You are also correct about the field name - should be `user_id` instead of `id` - thanks for that (corrected). Maybe a bit strange to have `user_id` = `username` - i.e. an `INT` field = a `VARCHAR`? No DDL, so who knows?

Comment: `(NOT) IN ( SELECT ... )` used to evaluate the subquery _every time_ -- very inefficient.  5.6 evaluates it once, builds a tmp table, and conjures up an index -- still more complex than `EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`.